# Update model with $http using a service not triggering model change

Tags: angularjs, http, model, angularjs-service

I have the following model:

```
 var MODEL = { myTable: [], anotherTable: [] }; //--- initially set as empty arrays
```

`MODEL` is a global variable as it is used to bind the app model in different controllers.

I have devined a service that updates the model, getting the data from a php page that returns the table rows:

```
myApp.factory('myAppUtils', function($http) {
     return {
            updateModelTable: function(tableName) {
                var pageToCall = "";
                var params = "";
                switch(tableName){
                    case 'myTable':
                        pageToCall = "myTable.php";
                        params = "";
                        break;
                    case 'anotherTable':
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                var updateModel = function(tableName, data){
                    MODEL[tableName] = data;
                };

                var url = "/" + pageToCall;
                $http.get(url).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        updateModel(tableName, data);
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert("error");
                    });
            }
        };
});
```

and then one of the controllers:

```
myApp.controller("MyTableCtrl", function($scope, myAppUtils){
    $scope.table = MODEL.myTable;
    myAppUtils.updateModelTable("playersTable");
});
```

once I run the app, the `myAppUtils.updateModelTable()` function is correctly invoked, it does update successfully the `MODEL` but the view controlled by `MyTableCtrl` does not update accordingly.

What I'm trying to do is to set up some sort of CRUD operations, getting and setting values from a sql db. I'd like to, for example, insert a new record and then call the update function to update the model and consequently the view, but this is not happening.

Is this the correct "angular" way to *do the thing*?

Any hint? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how about bind `$scope.model` to `MODEL` then access `{{model.myTable}}` in your view ?

Comment: It looks like you are first assigning `$scope.table` to equal `MODEL.myTable` (which is an empty array, at time of assignment), then you are updating the table, where you are replacing the empty array with an object in `MODEL`.  `$scope.table` is still equal to the empty array, though.

Comment: is there any specific reason that you must have a global variable holding all your table values? generally speaking, this is a bit of an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Claies I'm learning angular, so probably I'm making mistakes. How would you suggest to proceed? I'd like to share the same model between different views. I thought the global variable was a good way to do that

Comment: 1. Put MODEL to $rootScope. 2. Service should just return value.

Comment: @BeNdErR you can use a service as storage as it's singleton.

Comment: @Rebornix the view is correctly bound to the model. If I initialize MODEL.myTable with something, the view shows it correctly. Once I update the MODEL via $http instead the view is not updated accordingly

Comment: @BeNdErR just like Claies, hold a global variable in your code is not a good idea, a better solution is to create a service to share data between controllers, see my answer below. Besides, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507754/angular-js-api-using-a-factory/30507914#30507914 for more samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a global variable to share data between controllers, you can use a separate service to cache data, as Angular Service is singleton.

So in your case, create a service

```
myApp.service('modelService',function() {
    var model = {
      myTable: [],
      anotherTable: []
    };

    return model;
});
```

Then in your factory, inject this service and change your `updateModel` to

```
var updateModel = function(tableName, data){
    modelService.myTable = data;
};
```

And in your controller, inject `modelService` and bind it to `$scope` as

```
$scope.model = modelService;
```

Finally, in your view, you can access `model.myTable`, which can be updated automatically once you update them in your factory.

Comment: @Rebornix Yeah, finaly someone who know how to do it right. In addition you can read my answer to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508773/ngrepeat-not-updating-after-model-changed/30510369#30510369 that provide some information about a common issue with bindings into a factory/service with a controller.